# How to hide PowerShell startup advertisement?

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal, windows-terminal

When I using Ubuntu,the first line of terminal is prompt and my command.
But on Windows PowerShell,it shows an advertisement firstly each time I run terminal.
Is there any method to hide it?
I try to add cls command to profile but the effect is quite bad(the screen flicks).

[image: Ubuntu Terminal]
[image: Windows Terminal PowerShell Advertisement]

Comment: Edit the shortcut: "C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell.lnk" and add ` -NoLogo` to the end of the "Target"

Answer (score 0):

Add a call to the [`Clear-Host` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/clear-host?view=powershell-7.2) as the last statement in your [`$PROFILE` script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.2):

```
'Clear-Host' |Add-Content $PROFILE -Force
```

The profile script will run every time you launch PowerShell, and `Clear-Host` will then scroll the prompt to the top of the screen buffer, giving you a layout identical to the ubuntu terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I've tried this method and the window will blink on startup.
I would like to know if there is a better way to solve this problem.